# Can [tag:select] be used for selecting purposes but not from a database?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

Can [select](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select) tag be used for selecting purposes but *not from a database*?

When I check the user guidance of the [select](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select) tag, it says:

> The selection of data from a database based on some criteria.

If yes, I will request editing the description (maybe I will do it :)).

If no, which one shall I use instead: [select-by-attribute](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select-by-attribute), [select-by-location](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select-by-location), [select-by-expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select-by-expression)?

Here is an example: [Selecting random points from feature class](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/409140/selecting-random-points-from-feature-class). It is about a random selection from the attribute table, not a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that [select](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select) could be used for selecting any data in a GIS. A feature class is often in a database (file, personal, enterprise, mobile). There really is no difference to selecting data from a shapefile, or a non-spatial table (with the exception of selecting by location).

I would say this is an acceptable use of the [select](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select) tag.

I would support you editing the tag to include other uses.